# Divides Discrete Math by Contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I have a question about proof by contradiction. I understand how to do the following using contrapositive but not sure where to start if I had to prove by contradiction.

$\forall a,b,c \in Z, a \nmid bc \rightarrow a \nmid b $.

I did this by contrapositive with the following:

$a | b \rightarrow a | bc $

Given that a does divide b. Then $b = ak $ where $ k \in Z $.
Therefore,
$bc = akc = a(kc) = aq$ , where $q \in Z, q = kc$.
Therefore a divides b by defintion of divisibility so the original statement is true.

How would I go about doing this by contradiction?
I know it would be $a \nmid bc \rightarrow a|b$.

Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you're proving $A \rightarrow B$ by contradiction, you assume that $A$ is true and $B$ is false, and then show that this results in a contradiction. Then, if $A$ is true, $B$ can't be false, so $B$ must be true.

So in this case you don't want $a\nmid bc \rightarrow a|b$; you want $a \nmid bc \wedge a|b$. The beginning of your proof should go something like this:

"Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a \nmid bc$. Assume towards a contradiction that $a|b$..."

Then if you can get a contradiction from this, you've proved that $a \nmid b$.

Comment: I understand why its better but not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Use the definition of divisibility, like you did in the contrapositive proof. If $a|b$ then there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ak = b$. Then use this to show that $a|bc$.

Answer (score 0):

Contrapositive is of the form $-Q \implies -P$.

Contradiction is of the form $-Q$ and $P$ $\implies$ looney-tunes time.

So.  Assume $a\not\mid bc$ and $a\mid b$.  So $b = ak$ for some integer $k$.  And $bc \ne am$ for any integer.  No $bc = akc = a(kc)$ so $kc$ is not an integer even though both $k$ and $c$ are integers.

So the integers are not closed under multiplication.  And that's crazy talk.

---

That was a bit of an extreme.  In actuality if you can do a proof by contrapositive then you can do a contradiction simply by having you contradiction be $P $  and $-P$

Example:

Assume $a\not \mid bc$ and $a\mid b$. Then take your proof by contrapositive:

"a|b→a|bc"

"Given that a does divide b. Then b=ak
where k∈Z. Therefore, bc=akc=a(kc)=aq , where q∈Z,q=kc. Therefore a divides b by defintion of divisibility so the original statement is true."

But the original statement is *not* true.  You have *proven* $a|b$ but we are given as a hypothesis that $a\not \mid b$.  So we have $a|b$ *IS* a contradiction.  Because we assumed that $a$ does *NOT* divide $b$.

That's it.

That's enough.